# Displaying instagram pictures

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, instagram

How to obtain random pictures from instagram and display it on web? Note: not pictures of recent postings.

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe src="http://igram.github.com/?tag=cool" width=500 height=230 frameborder=0>
</iframe>
```